# Displaying video in WPF from RTSP

Tags: c#, wpf, video-streaming

I am attempting to display a video stream in a WPF application that I am receiving via an ad-hoc connection to a Raspberry Pi. The video is streamed over the connection via RTSP, and sent in a h.264 video format. For the life of me, I cannot seem to figure out to display the video in the application.

Below is some of what I have right now, although I am not very sure any of it is useful for what I am trying to do.

XAML:

```
<MediaElement Name="stream" Height="720" Width="1280" Margin="54,10,54,240" Source="{Binding Video}" ></MediaElement>
```

C#:

```
    private Uri _ROVVideo;
    public Uri ROVVideo
    {
        get
        {
            return _ROVVideo;
        }
        set
        {
            _ROVVideo = value;
            //OnPropertyChanged("something");
        }
    }
```

I've looked into using some libraries such as EmguCV but it doesn't really seem to be exactly what I want to use to solve this problem. Has anyone done anything like this before and/or have recommendations on how to get started? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a `http-URL`?

Comment: Do stream broadcasters need a URL for the listener to pick it up? I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: No, but if you have a URL than it is easy to implement in WPF: you just set the source property.